# Can anyone indentify this component?

Tags: identification, components

I have no clue of the PCB where this component was.
[image]
The reference H400 60 and a logo that is unreadable are located in the top of the package.
[image]
I didn't found any datasheet or valuable information in google.
There's a metal holder and a small cylinder inside the part.
[image]

[image]

The small cilinder appears to be  made by two materials.

The inside material is condutive.

The outside material is isolant.

I can't measure any capacitance in the cylinder.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you measure any voltage or resistance between the two sides?

Comment: No voltage is present. Resistance is very small (32 Ohms with 
 a Fluke 87V)

Comment: looks like a solid state starting relay for a refrigerator compressor

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This looks very much a like a power PTC used for example for demagnetizing cathode-ray tubes. The ceramic gets high-resistance when it heats up.

And indeed, googling for "H400 PTC" yields e.g. [this link at a random seller offering a component looking alike](https://recambios.eurofred.es/catalog/product/view/id/94200/s/termistor-ash12lsacw-f-235/category/3686/), but I was unable to quickly find a data sheet.

Comment: I agree with it being a ptc, the numbers also verify ptc as possible component

Comment: I agree component is a Ptc as the number indicates ptc